# Ant Design TimePickers scrolls with the page

Tags: reactjs, datetimepicker, antd

I'm using antd `TimePicker` when I open it and scroll down, the popover scrolls with the page instead of staying in place.
I cant figure out why their official solution for the scrolling problem isn't working for me
https://ant.design/docs/react/faq#How-do-I-prevent-Select-Dropdown-DatePicker-TimePicker-Popover-Popconfirm-scrolling-with-the-page

Here is my code:

```
    <div className="timepicker__wrapper">
      <span className="timepicker__mintime-label">
        {getTranslate(QUESTION_MODULE.GENERAL.MINIMUM_TIME_LABEL)}
      </span>
      <TimePicker
        getPopupContainer={triggerNode => triggerNode.parentNode}
        onChange={onChangeMinTime}
        format={timeFormat}
        defaultValue={moment(item.minTime ?? '00:00', timeFormat)}
        allowClear={false}
       
      />
    </div>
```

If I `console.log` `triggerNode.parentNode` it points to the `timepicker__wrapper` exactly as it should.
Here you can see the anchor node

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by adding `position: relative` to the anchor node. It would be nice to mention this in the docs